# How to plot Kmeans clusters on a folium map?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, folium

My question relates to plotting the Kmeans clusters on a folium map.
I have implemented Kmeans clustering to create 10 clusters as follows:

```
#centers = np.array(Kmeans_pca.cluster_centers_)
model = KMeans(n_clusters = 10, init = "k-means++")
label = model.fit_predict(reduced95)
centers = model.cluster_centers_
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
uniq = np.unique(label)
for i in uniq:
    plt.scatter(reduced95[label == i , 0] , reduced95[label == i , 2] , label = i)
plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], marker="x", color='k')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I also plot a particular region on folium as follow:

```
lat = -25.2744
long = 133.7751
import folium
m = folium.Map(location = [lat,long ], tiles ='OpenStreetMap',      
    zoom_start=4)
m
```

Dataset looks like this:

|  | header1 | geometry | ..... | header_n | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| idx1 | place1 | (POLYGON ((149.52424 -35.44426,149.416 -35.4..) | ..... | 8736473 | 1 |
| idx2 | place2 | (POLYGON ((149.1645 -35.4321, 149.332 -35.4..) | ..... | 1374619 | 5 |
| idx3 | place3 | (POLYGON ((148.1278 -35.763, 149.2344 -35.4..) | ..... | 8736473 | 0 |
| idx4 | place4 | (POLYGON ((149.0978 -35.0963, 149.76444 -35.4..) | ..... | 1374619 | 9 |

I want to create a folium map which can plot the clusters (created by KMeans) on to the map.
So far I am able to create a map which plots using geometry from the dataframe. But now I also want to visualise the Kmeans clusters.  How do I do it?

EDIT:

I have an update towards solution, but it still fails to make a map.

So, I have created these two variables which belong to clusters 1 & 2.

```
color1 = gdf[gdf['cluster'] == 0].index
color2 = gdf[gdf['cluster'] == 1].index
```

Next step: mapping

```
gdf['color'] = gdf.index.map(lambda x: 'red' if x in color1 else 'blue')
```

Last step: visualise:

```
cluster_map = gdf.explore(column='color', cmap=['red', 'blue'], legend=True)
```

It does not even show any errors or warnings. Not sure, where I am going wrong in this.

Comment: in markdown you need an extra line break between a table definition and another paragraph. edited to fix.

Comment: what is it you want to plot? are you just asking how to make a scatter plot of the centers in folium?

Comment: Yes (on folium). However, I don't know how to find centres using geometry. In the dataframe, I only have geometry, no latitude or longitude.

Comment: Basically, how to go about visualising KMeans clusters or DBSCAN clusters on folium map?

Answer (score 0):

If that dataset you show above is a geodataframe, the easiest way to show the clusters on a folium map is to use the `explore` method that creates one.

```py
gdf.explore('cluster', categorical=True)
```

Comment: Yes, it's a geodataframe. 
I tried this method, but it does not show any plot at the end. Is there anything I am doing wrong? 
Also, I was wondering if I need to specify a color for each cluster number?

Comment: What is your environment? Jupyter notebook or something else? Colours are assigned automatically but you can override that.

Comment: Yes, jupyter notebook is my env. I am not really sure what's happening. I also have created a dictionary like this: 
```
colors =['#ff0000','#FFFF00','#0000FF','#000000', '#008000']
color_dict = dict(zip(np.unique(ASGS_clustering['cluster']),colors))
```
But, it's still not assigning the cluster a color in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = gdf.explore(
 column="cluster",  # make choropleth based on column
 #scheme="Percentiles",  # use mapclassify's natural 
 breaks scheme
 legend=True, # show legend
 k=1, # number of bins
 legend_kwds=dict(colorbar=True), # do not use colorbar
 #name="Trips" # name of the layer in the map,
#cmap='tab10'
)
m
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).